# import and package statements apply to all classes within a source code file

Tags: java

I'm reading a java book and came along the following paragraph:

> import and package statements apply to all classes within a source
>   code file. In other words, there's no way to declare multiple classes
>   in a file and have them in different packages or use different
>   imports.

I'm having difficulties understanding this paragraph, can please someone explain me the idea behind it?

Comment: Please provide the book, for reference.

Comment: The simple way I'd think of it is that Java doesn't give us a way to use an import statement for an inner class, but rather the import applies to the whole file we are in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare multiple classes in a single file, eg the following will define the classes `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz`:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Foo {

    public class Bar {}

}

class Baz {}
```

There can only be one top level public class per file, in this case `Foo`.

Notice the package statement; this applies to all classes within the file; all the classes are in the '`com.example`' namespace - you cannot have `Foo` in '`com.example`' and `Bar` in '`com.example.something`'

The imports are applicable to all classes in this file; you cannot only make the imports available to `Baz` (or any subset of the classes declared in the file)

You may be wondering what `Bar` is doing declared within the `Foo` class; this is an inner class - the (somewhat sparse) oracle tutorial regarding inner classes is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

Comment: You can have multiple top-level classes in a single file, there is only one allowed to be public.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, a single source code file contains a single, public class definition:

```
package com.example;
public class FirstClass {
}
```

Multiple classes can be defined as top-level in the file, but only one can be public:

```
package com.example;
public class FirstClass {
}
class SecondClass {
}
```

This is the case to which your paragraph refers: all top-level classes declared in the file are within the same package: `com.example` in this case.

Also classes can be defined in various inner scopes, such as within a class as static or non-static, or within a method

```
package com.example;
public class Outer {
    static class StaticInner { }
    class Inner {}
    void method(){
        class MethodInner {}
    }
}
```

These are effectively also in the same package, though they are scoped within the enclosing class as well and not simply package-level classes.

There are various definitions for how to construct and access inner classes and how they are named, but that seems to be beyond the scope of your initial question.